# How to add some data to .jpg or .mp4 file in android

Tags: android

Business Purpose :

1) Want to add large string(data) of length 1200 to the .jpg / .mp4 file in android mobile
2) Later the file can be uploaded to server from mobile
3) In server we retrieve the added data from the file

What i have tried in .jpg file : 
Used the below code for adding data 
`ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
exif.setAttribute("UserComment", "String having length of 1000");
exif.saveAttributes();`

This code is working. After i set the attribute, i can able to read it by

`String userComment=exif.getAttribute("UserComment");`

In low end mobile it showed error "stack corruption detected: aborted" while saving attribute.Later i found it taken up to 663 characters alone.
In high end mobile the string of length saved up to 1999 after saveAttribute().

Is there any other way to add some tag/meta data/string to **.jpg,.mp4** and **.mp3** file ?
So that the added data can be retrieved later.

please share your views. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if it's certainly is possible using your approach, but you're running into various implementation limits in how long attribute values are supported.

One solution to at least investigate is of course to split your 1200-byte string into multiple shorter strings, say four 300-byte ones, and add those as `UserComment0`, `UserComment1` and so on. That should be trivial to extract and concatenate to get back your original longer string, and might work around the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Praveen,

take a look at Steganography project

https://github.com/johnkil/Steganography

Thanks,
Jey.